# "describe is not defined" mocha (windows user)

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, mocha.js

i was trying to test this

```
 var assert = require("assert");


describe("test suite math opreations",function(){

    it("add of two",function(){

        var a = 10;
        var b = 10;

        var c = a+b;

        assert.equal(c,20);

    });

    it("sub of two",function(){

        var a = 10;
        var b = 10;

        var c = a-b;

        assert.equal(c,0);

    });

    it("multi of two",function(){

        var a = 10;
        var b = 10;

        var c = a*b;

        assert.equal(c,100);

    });

    it("division of two",function(){

        var a = 10;
        var b = 10;

        var c = a/b;

        assert.equal(c,1);

    });
});
```

the file name is test
and changed the direction to the file in the terminal
and wrote

```
node test.js
```

and the terminal said "describe is not defined"

i tried alot of things

re install nodes and mocha

move the file to alot of folders

and finally.....i didn't solve the problem :)

Comment: You cannot run it with `node`. You need to run it with `mocha` as in `mocha test.js`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install mocha, and then run this test file with its binary.

You can either install it to your project dependencies with `npm i -D mocha`, then add a new npm script for example "test" and make it run "mocha" from your node_modules:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^10.2.0"
  }
}
```

And then just use `npm test`, or `npm run test`.

or, you can install it globally on your machine with `npm i -g mocha` and then run

`mocha` instead of your `node test.js` command.

Please refer to: https://mochajs.org/#getting-started